# draggable ui that implicate a condition on specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am struggling in a specific problem. I actually have a draggable element based on a grid of 4 and I would like to create an event each time the draggable item reaches a specific position on this gird.

Here is the html of this grid,

```
<div class="selector">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>Vælg lånebeløb</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable">
    <h3 id="krd">kr</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    <img src="./resources/images/line.png" alt="line">
  </div>
  <div class="legend">
    <p>3.000</p>
    <p>4.000</p>
    <p>5.000</p>
    <p>6.000</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the jquery,

```
$("#krd").draggable({
  grid: [ 190, 0 ],
  cursor: "move",
  containment: '.selector',
  drag: function( event, ui ) {
    if(ui.position.left = 190) {
    $(".bluebox h2").text("3.000 Kr");
    } else if (ui.position.left = 380) {
      ect......
    } {

    }
  }
});
```

What I am trying to do is that when we move the bar, it changes the text in the sidebar. I tried different options since but couldn't figure out what I am missing. Here is the link of the page on github of the project, maybe you will have an idea about it.

Here is the link of the code in github 
**https://github.com/erwanriou/goKredit---Frontpage/**

and the render of the page to get a better idea of the problem.
**https://erwanriou.github.io/goKredit---Frontpage/**

Comment: I would advise using `.slider()` instead. You can theme it and adjust it to work on steps. A lot less work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding upon my comment, I would advise using jQuery UI Slider. You will need to theme it, but the code would be:

```
$(function() {
  $("#krd").slider({
    min: 3,
    max: 6,
    value: 3,
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      $(".bluebox h2").text(ui.value + ".000 Kr");
    }
  });
});
```

Example (in progress): https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bjfuLjzL/2/

Comment: Thank you, its seems its work perfectly now! I will just add some stats on it and i would have all the changes in the text i want :)